# How to add two listviews in a single layout in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hello I am working on demo application where I need to add two `listview` such first `listview` then below of this second `listview`.

I am trying like below but if I add more items in first `listview` then second `listview` items does not display because complete full screen height occupy by first `listview`.

I want it should scroll instead of either small space of second `listview`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/firstListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/secondListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using weights? that way you can assign a percentage of the screen height to each list instead of wrapping content.

Comment: @Santiago I tried weight but I don't want to use weight . I want occupy as much space as items of first listview require then as much space as items of second listview but all should scroll.

Comment: Does it makes sense? I don't think so, because the first ListView will occupy the whole screen if you do not specify a concrete height or weight (with linear layout) ...

Comment: @sockeqwe but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my probem. This made to add two listview in a single `activity` one after another `list`.

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: Can you also include your layout?  Are you still using wrapContent for their height?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, that works fine for me

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/firstListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/secondListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstListView">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```